# Not able to get the xpathcount using Webdriver with Java

Tags: java, xpath, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Not able to get the xpathcount using Webdriver. By using the below code I am getting count as 0.

```
int xpathcount= driver.findElements(By.xpath(("//table[@id='ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_GrdHistory']/tbody/tr"))).size();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Then the XPath is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The xpath is correct, it worked in Selenium RC. Now the xpath is working without any change in it.

Comment: Are the elements visible when the page loads? Sounds like they aren't, sounds like there is a race or timing problem, considering it's working now and you've changed nothing.

Comment: Yes, there is a timing problem, I have increased the sleep time before the taking the xpathcount. Then it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, you had some trouble with parentheses...

```
int xpathcount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='ctl00_MasterPlaceHolder_GrdHistory']/tbody/tr")).size();
```